# Assert MockMvc response by using Kotlin DSL

Tags: kotlin, spring, dsl

I build web application using Kotlin and Spring Boot, I use MockMvc to write integration test.

I'm not satisfied how assertion looks like, here is typical assertion:

```kotlin
        @Test
        fun `Get profile by id`() {
            thereIsATeacher(lissaSkipper)

            mockMvc.get("/teacher/{id}", "52058608")
                .andExpect {
                    status { isOk() }
                    jsonPath("$.id") { value("52058608") }
                    jsonPath("$.slug") { value("lissa-skipper-math-teacher") }
                }
        }
```

the `jsonPath("$.id") { value("52058608") }`, for me, is not good enough, but it's very popular.
I spent a few hours and tried to build "domain assertion", using DSL. Now the test looks:

```kotlin
        @Test
        fun `Get profile by id`() {
            thereIsATeacher(lissaSkipper)

            mockMvc.get("/teacher/{id}", "52058608")
                .andExpect {
                    status { isOk() }

                    teacherProfile {
                        id("52058608")
                        slug("lissa-skipper-math-teacher")
                        profilePhoto {
                            url("https://example.com/photo.jpg")
                            alt("Lissa Skipper - math teacher")
                        }
                        joined("2023-01-22T10:00:00Z")
                    }
                }
        }
```

and here are assertion classes

```kotlin
class TeacherProfileRestAssertion internal constructor(private val dsl: MockMvcResultMatchersDsl) {

    fun id(expectedValue: String) {
        dsl.jsonPath("$.id") { value(expectedValue) }
    }

    fun slug(expectedValue: String) {
        dsl.jsonPath("$.slug") { value(expectedValue) }
    }

    fun profilePhoto(imageAssertion: ImageRestAssertion.() -> Unit) {
        ImageRestAssertion(dsl, "$.profilePhoto").apply(imageAssertion)
    }
// ...
}

fun MockMvcResultMatchersDsl.teacherProfile(assertion: TeacherProfileRestAssertion.() -> Unit) {
    TeacherProfileRestAssertion(this).apply(assertion)
}

class ImageRestAssertion internal constructor(
    private val dsl: MockMvcResultMatchersDsl,
    private val jsonPrefix: String = "$"
) {

    fun url(expectedValue: String) {
        dsl.jsonPath("$jsonPrefix.url") { value(expectedValue) }
    }
//....
}
```

What do you think? It's a good idea to hide `jsonPaths` behins such dsl assertions?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm leaning toward `yes`. Hiding the `jsonPath` behind a more domain-specific DSL has several advantages:

**Readability**: Your custom DSL makes the tests more readable, as it describes the expected structure of the response in a more human-friendly way. This makes it easier for other developers to understand the test cases.

**Maintainability**: Using a custom DSL helps you encapsulate the structure of the response in one place. If the API response structure changes, you'll need to update your DSL assertions only, rather than updating multiple test cases individually.

**Reusability**: Your custom DSL is reusable across different test cases. This will lead to less code duplication and improved maintainability.

**Test abstraction**: By hiding the `jsonPath` details, your tests become more focused on the behavior and business requirements, rather than the implementation details of the API responses.

However, what I don't really like:

**Learning curve:** A custom DSL might introduce a learning curve for developers who are not familiar with it. They will need to understand the DSL before they can effectively write and update tests.

**Complexity**: Introducing a custom DSL adds an additional layer of abstraction, sometimes leading to increased complexity in your test codebase.

As long as you keep your DSL simple and well-documented, the benefits of increased readability, maintainability, and reusability will likely outweigh the potential trade-offs.